# Phase response curve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, process-control

I just want to plot the phase response curve (phase vs. frequency curve) for the following nonlinear differential equation:

```
x''[t]*x[t]+3/2*x'[t]^2==x[t]^(-3*k)-1-4*\[Beta]*x'[t]/x[t]+f*Sin[\[CapitalOmega]*t]
```

Where `k=7/5`, `f=0.2`, `\[Beta]=0.03`
I have no idea that how can I get it numerically.
Hoping for help.
Thanks

Comment: What is \[CapitalOmega]?

Comment: `\[CapitalOmega]` is the forcing frequency.

Comment: Right, but don't we need a value for a numerical solution along with two initial conditions?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. The initial conditions are `x[0]=1` and `x'[0]=0`. I want to plot it for the steady state condition and `\[CapitalOmega]` is varying from `-5` to `5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phase information follows from the optimal trigonometric approximation

[image: X\[\[CapitalOmega\]\]\[t\]~a+b Sin\[\[CapitalOmega t+phase\]=a+c Cos\[\[CapitalOmega t\]+s Sin\[\[CapitalOmega t\]]

(fundamentals of FourierSeries)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
k = 7/5; f = 1/5; β = 3/100;
tmax = 20;

sys = {
x''[t]*x[t] + 3/2*x'[t]^2 ==x[t]^(-3*k) - 1 - 4*β*x'[t]/x[t] + f*Sin[Ω*t],
x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0} // Simplify;

X= ParametricNDSolveValue[sys, x, {t, 0, tmax}, {Ω}]
```

Thanks @BobHanlon for these code lines!

```
phase[\[CapitalOmega]_?NumericQ] := 
Block[{acs, 
M = NIntegrate[Outer[Times, {1, Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t],Sin[\[CapitalOmega] t]}, {1, Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t],Sin[\[CapitalOmega] t]}], {t, 0, tmax},Method -> "LocalAdaptive"],
rS = NIntegrate[X[\[CapitalOmega]][t] {1, Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t],Sin[\[CapitalOmega] t]}, {t, 0, tmax},Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]}, 
acs = LinearSolve[M, rS ];
ArcTan[acs[[2]], acs[[3]]]]
```

plot result

```
zw = Table[{\[CapitalOmega],phase[\[CapitalOmega]]}, {\[CapitalOmega], Subdivide[0 , 5, 25]}]

ListPlot[zw, Joined -> True,AxesLabel -> {\[CapitalOmega], "phase[\[CapitalOmega]]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich Neumann. It worked for my problem.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

k = 7/5; f = 1/5; β = 3/100;

tmax = 20;

sys = {
    x''[t]*x[t] + 3/2*x'[t]^2 == 
     x[t]^(-3*k) - 1 - 4*β*x'[t]/x[t] + f*Sin[Ω*t],
    x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0} // Simplify;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[sys, x, {t, 0, tmax}, {Ω}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x[Ω][t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, x})],
 {{Ω, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon, but I want to plot steady state phase vs. frequency curve